# How to set the value of a field "reference to a term" with the use of entity_metadata_wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

In a content type with a have taxonomy field "reference to a term" which I want to connect to a webform submission.

I have the following code in rules:

```
$brancheid = $submissions[$sid]->data[1][0];
$oplossingsid = $submissions[$sid]->data[2][0];
$nodeid = $submissions[$sid]->data[3][0];

$node = node_load($nodeid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node_wrapper->title->set('done');   // this is working
$node_wrapper->save();
$node_wrapper->field_sector->set($brancheid);
$node_wrapper->field_dienst->set($oplossingsid);
$node_wrapper->save();
```

After submission of the webform the title is saved. But field_sector and field_dienst (taxonomy reference to a term types) and are not saved. I tried several combinations but do not get it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. This is not working:

```
$node_wrapper->field_sector->set($brancheid);
$node_wrapper->field_dienst->set($oplossingsid);
```

But this is working:

```
$node_wrapper->field_sector = $brancheid;
$node_wrapper->field_dienst = $oplossingsid;
```

Comment: If it is reference field, it should accept array of IDs.